# How to use re function in python

Tags: python

I have the following list :

```
 ['[infotype02]', 'lastModifiedOn = serial<customMapping>', 'customString18 = BADGE_NUMBER<move>', 'firstName = FIRST_NAME<move>', 'lastName = LAST_NAME<move>', 'customString29 = USER_NAME<move>', 'email = EMAIL_ADDRESS<move>', 'documenttype = DOC_TYPE<move>', 'documentnumber = DOC_SERIA<customMapping>', 'documentnumberx2 = DOC_NUMBER<customMapping>', 'issuedate = DOC_ISSUE_DATE<move>', 'issueauthority = DOC_ISSUER<move>', 'nationalId = CNP<move>', 'company = COMPANY<move>', 'phoneNumber = PHONE_NUMBER<move>', 'startDate = HIRE_DATE<customMapping>', 'startDatex2 = TERMINATION_DATE<customMapping>', '[/infotype02]', '[infotype02]', 'lastModifiedOn = serial<customMapping>', 'customString18 = BADGE_NUMBER<move>', 'firstName = FIRST_NAME<move>', 'lastName = LAST_NAME<move>', 'customString29 = USER_NAME<move>', 'email = EMAIL_ADDRESS<move>', 'documenttype = DOC_TYPE<move>', 'documentnumber = DOC_SERIA<customMapping>', 'documentnumberx2 = DOC_NUMBER<customMapping>', 'issuedate = DOC_ISSUE_DATE<move>', 'issueauthority = DOC_ISSUER<move>', 'nationalId = CNP<move>', 'company = COMPANY<move>', 'phoneNumber = PHONE_NUMBER<move>', 'startDate = HIRE_DATE<customMapping>', 'startDatex2 = TERMINATION_DATE<customMapping>', '[/infotype02]']
```

for i in list; i = `[infotype02]`

I tried using re expression to get the string between the [], expected result `infotype02` :

```
        result = re.search('[(.*)]', i)
```

Then tried to append the result.group(1) to a new list and it returned an error :

```
    lst.append(result.group(1))
    AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

I don't understand what is wrong with my re expresion and why isn't it finding the string between the []

Comment: What do you want the output to be ?

Comment: try using this expression `r"\[.*]"`

Comment: @ZainArshad, the text between the `[]` and for `[infotype02]`, I expect to get `infotype02`

Comment: @Shahir same outcome, still dosen't find anything

Comment: From the whole given list you just want to get the text of the element that is enclosed with '[ ]' ?

Comment: So for example in given list at the end you just want a new list like : `[infotype02, /infotype02]`

Comment: I want the value between the `[]` without the `/` but for now it would be ok even to return the text between the `[]` Edit or better said, just the value without the `/` and for the value with / to ignore it, i assume the re could do that if i just make it like this `re.search('[/(.*)]', i)`

Comment: So for example `lst = [infotype02][/infotype02]` a new list with only `newlst =[infotype02]`

Comment: Square brackets have special meaning in regex. They construct a character group so your pattern is looking for one of the literal characters `(.*)`. If you want to look for literal square brackets you need to escape them: `r"\[(.*)\]"`. Check the [demo](https://regex101.com/r/GlRA7Q/2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use a simple `for-loop` to accomplish this:

```
data = ['[infotype02]', 'lastModifiedOn = serial<customMapping>', 'customString18 = BADGE_NUMBER<move>', 'firstName = FIRST_NAME<move>', 
    'lastName = LAST_NAME<move>', 'customString29 = USER_NAME<move>', 'email = EMAIL_ADDRESS<move>', 'documenttype = DOC_TYPE<move>', 
    'documentnumber = DOC_SERIA<customMapping>', 'documentnumberx2 = DOC_NUMBER<customMapping>', 'issuedate = DOC_ISSUE_DATE<move>', 
    'issueauthority = DOC_ISSUER<move>', 'nationalId = CNP<move>', 'company = COMPANY<move>', 'phoneNumber = PHONE_NUMBER<move>', 
    'startDate = HIRE_DATE<customMapping>', 'startDatex2 = TERMINATION_DATE<customMapping>', '[/infotype02]', '[infotype02]', 
    'lastModifiedOn = serial<customMapping>', 'customString18 = BADGE_NUMBER<move>', 'firstName = FIRST_NAME<move>', 'lastName = LAST_NAME<move>',
    'customString29 = USER_NAME<move>', 'email = EMAIL_ADDRESS<move>', 'documenttype = DOC_TYPE<move>', 'documentnumber = DOC_SERIA<customMapping>', 
    'documentnumberx2 = DOC_NUMBER<customMapping>', 'issuedate = DOC_ISSUE_DATE<move>', 'issueauthority = DOC_ISSUER<move>', 'nationalId = CNP<move>', 
    'company = COMPANY<move>', 'phoneNumber = PHONE_NUMBER<move>', 'startDate = HIRE_DATE<customMapping>', 'startDatex2 = TERMINATION_DATE<customMapping>', 
    '[/infotype02]']

new_list = []
for d in data:
    if d[0] == '[' and not d[1] == '/':
    #if re.match(r"\[[^/](.*)\]", d): # If you want to use `re`
        new_list.append(d[1:-1])

print(new_list)
```

**Output:**

> ['infotype02', 'infotype02']

As you have 2 of these tags in your given list.

Comment: Using `[^/]` is not a good idea. It will consume the first character and avoid matching strings starting with `/`

Comment: Yes that exactly OP wants, he don't want to match strings starting with /

Comment: Oh you're right I misunderstood OP on that (was not very clear). Anyway this will consume the first letter, so `[infotype02]` will become `nfotype02`

Comment: No it won't, i Would suggest you to run this program first

Comment: Assuming we take the group, it will... [Have a look](https://regex101.com/r/pYJPwS/1). You might to change to `\[([^/].*)\]`